# What is the cause of this error 'javax.faces.FacesException: var attribute must be set' and how to fixed this?

Tags: jsf-2, seam, facelets

I encountered this problem in my apps. The weird part was this error popups at some moment i started my apps but sometimes it does not.

The piece of the stacktrace..

```
javax.faces.FacesException: var attribute must be set
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.component.UISelectItems$ContextualSelectItem.<init>(UISelectItems.java:58)
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.component.UISelectItems$1.<init>(UISelectItems.java:219)
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.component.UISelectItems.asSelectItems(UISelectItems.java:195)
    at org.jboss.seam.ui.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:178)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.getSelectItems(RenderKitUtils.java:289)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.renderSelect(MenuRenderer.java:814)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.encodeEnd(MenuRenderer.java:280)
```

I think the source of my error has something to do with h:selectOneMenu but i defined my var attribute correctly in my selectItems.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.user}">
   <s:selectItems value="#{myBean.userList}" var="_user" label="#{_user.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Has anyone encountered this problem please help.
I've done a couple of research but found no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the code for your `h:selectOneMenu`?

Comment: Have you tried with the `_` on the var? Just `userVar` for instance. Also ensure you are using the latest version of seam, specially if you are using jsf2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can have 2 causes:

1. The `#{myBean.userList}` has returned `null` or an empty list.
2. The `#{_user}` is already been declared beforehand in the scope.

To solve it:

1. Make sure that `#{myBean.userList}` does not return `null` nor is empty.
2. Make sure that you haven't used `#{_user}` anywhere else in the view. Give it a different name.

Comment: You nail it master :))..I have two declaration of var attribute on my view..I change the other name of my var and the error is gone.thnx

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen when a page is rendered or is there something more specific about the times when it arises. My suggestion is that somewhere you have something like [this](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_dataTable.html) without the `var` defined and this causes the error. Try looking [here](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_selectOneMenu.html) to see how to use `h:selectOneMenu`.

Comment: it happens upon page load..navigation..my var attribute is set in s:selectItems. Sometimes this error arises and sometimes not.